# Is it possible to check the exact type of parameterized generics at runtime in Python ^3.10?

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, typing, python-3.10

I have some custom type definitions using parameterized generics. Now at runtime, I want to find out if a variable does have this custom type. Here's a minimal example:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Callable
>>> MyType = Callable[[int], int]
>>> my_fun: MyType = lambda x: x
>>> isinstance(my_fun, MyType)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() argument 2 cannot be a parameterized generic
```

Is there any way to achieve this currently?

Comment: Are you hoping that `isinstance` check will return `True`? Because the function object doesn't carry any information about the `MyType` annotation, so you're pretty much screwed there.

Comment: Yeah, that was my hope :) Open to third-party solutions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what you are trying to achieve with this, but assuming the annotation is done in module scope and you are dealing with the same variable name, you can always just refer to the [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annassign) dictionary and utilize [`get_args`/`get_origin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args):

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import get_args, get_origin


MyType = Callable[[int], int]
my_fun: MyType = lambda x: x

my_fun_annotation = __annotations__["my_fun"]

assert get_origin(my_fun_annotation) is Callable
assert get_args(my_fun_annotation) == ([int], int)
```

But you should probably explain a bit more, why you think you need to do this because it seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Of course there are many different way of approaching most issues, for me it was most interesting if there is a way in python to solve this specific problem. The above solution is quite interesting!
More context: I have a bunch of functions as union typed input to a higher order function and depending on the type the logic is slightly different. In the end, I solved it by making the interfaces of those functions identical, thus eliminating the polymorphism problem and making the additional logic superfluous.